# Merge Nodes on the basis of attribute id using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I have facing problem in merging the nodes and placing them into a new node on the basis of attribute values. My source XML looks like -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Rep><RepData>
<Row>
<Field name="ID">A</Field>
<Field name="CName">Angle</Field>
<Field name="GPL">A-G</Field>
</Row>
<Row>
<Field name="ID">J-A</Field>
<Field name="CName">J-A-Ang</Field>
<Field name="GPL">GPL_A-J</Field>
</Row>
<Row>
<Field name="ID">J-U</Field>
<Field name="CName">J-U-Ang</Field>
<Field name="GPL">GPL_A-U</Field>
</Row>
<Row>
<Field name="ID">J-I</Field>
<Field name="CName">J-I-Ang</Field>
<Field name="GPL">GPL_A-I</Field>
</Row>
<Row>
<Field name="ID">M</Field>
<Field name="CName">Ma</Field>
<Field name="GPL">A-M</Field>
</Row>
</RepData>
</Rep>
```

The XSLT I am using is as below -

```
  <xsl:template match="/Rep/Report">
         <ccs>
           <xsl:for-each-group select="Row" group-by="Field[@name='ID']">
                <ccwc>
                           <xsl:variable name="ref">
                                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$ref"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <name>
                                <xsl:if test="string-length(Field[@name='CName']) != 0">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Field[@name='CName']"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="string-length(Field[@name='CName']) =0">
                                    Unknown
                                </xsl:if>
                            </name>
                            <cccs>
                                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Field[@name='GPL']">
                                    <ccc>
                                        <xsl:variable name="childRef">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="fullRef">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$ref,$childRef"></xsl:value-of>
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$fullRef"/>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <name>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                                        </name>
                                    </ccc>
                                </xsl:for-each-group>
                            </cccs>
                        </ccwc>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
        </ccs>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Using above XSLT, the output XML I am getting is -

```
    <ccwc id="A">
        <name>Angle</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="A A-G">
                <name>A-G</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccwc>
    <ccwc id="J-A">
        <name>J-A-Ang</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="J-A A-J">
                <name>A-J</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccwc>
    <ccwc id="J-U">
        <name>J-U-Ang</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="J-U A-U">
                <name>A-U</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccwc>
    <ccwc id="J-I">
        <name>J-I-Ang</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="J-I A-I">
                <name>A-I</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccwc>
    <ccwc id="M">
        <name>Ma</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="M A-M">
                <name>A-M</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccwc>
</ccs>
```

I want to merge the nodes where `<Field name="ID">` starts with 'J' and put them all under one  new node and rest of the hierarchy should remain same. My Expected XML should look like -

```
    <ccwc id="A">
        <name>Angle</name>
        <cccs>
            <ccc id="A A-G">
                <name>A-G</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccwc>
    <ccwc id="1-J">
      <name>One J</name>
      <cccs>
          <ccc id ="1-J_J-A">
           <name>J-A-Ang</name>
           <cccs>
            <ccc id="1-J_J-A_GPL_A-J">
                <name>GPL_A-J</name>
            </ccc>
        </cccs>
        </ccc>
          <ccc id ="1-J_J-U">
           <name>J-U-Ang</name>
           <cccs>
            <ccc id="1-J_J-U_GPL_A-U">
                <name>GPL_A-U</name>
            </ccc>
           </cccs>
        </ccc>
          <ccc id ="1-J_J-I">
              <name>J-I-Ang</name>           
              <ccc id="1-J_J-I_GPL_A-I">
                <name>GPL_A-I</name>
            </ccc>
          </ccc>
      </cccs> 
    </ccwc> 
    <ccwc id="M">
        <name>Ma</name>
        <cccs>
    <ccc id="M A-M">
                <name>A-M</name>
    </ccc>
        </cccs>
    </ccwc>
</ccs>
```

I am not able to understand where should I break the grouping and add the new node. I am using XSLT 2.0 version. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the top-level grouping structure with a check like

```
  <xsl:template match="/Rep/RepData">
    <ccs>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Row" group-by="if (Field[@name = 'ID'][starts-with(., 'J')]) then 'J' else Field[@name = 'ID']">
        <ccwc id="{current-grouping-key()}"></ccwc>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ccs>
  </xsl:template>
```

This gives e.g.

```
<ccs>
   <ccwc id="A"/>
   <ccwc id="J"/>
   <ccwc id="M"/>
</ccs>
```

I have not spelled out the inner grouping but I guess it remains as you have it; I have also not fully understood the rules on how to convert the input `J` data to `1-J` so I have not attempted to implement it, it might be as easy as doing e.g. `group-by="if (Field[@name = 'ID'][starts-with(., 'J')]) then '1-J' else Field[@name = 'ID']"`.

Comment: Basically I want to put all the J's data i.e J-A, J-U and J-I under one single `J`. `1-J' I am using just to make the id's unique.

Comment: @user13583928, I think the answer above shows how to put all `J` data with e.g. `group-by="if (Field[@name = 'ID'][starts-with(., 'J')]) then 'J' else Field[@name = 'ID']"` in one group. The comments about the differences in the shown result and your wanted result are just meant to indicate that you need to adapt the suggestion to your exact needs.